# Ruby コードを HTML に埋め込み、ブラウザで閲覧時に実行させたい

Tags: ruby

Ruby を学び始めたばかりですが、

Rails ではなく、 pure な状態の Ruby をブラウザから実行したいのですが、 (PHP でいう index.php　のような形) ということは ubuntu + nginx の環境からできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「ruby をブラウザから実行したい」と言われますと回答者の多くは http://opalrb.org/try/# これを紹介してしまうかと思います。

Comment: +1 for opalrb /// 件名を 「ruby をブラウザから実行したい」 から 「Ruby コードを HTML に埋め込み、ブラウザで閲覧時に実行させたい」 に変更しました。

Comment: タイトル変更ありがとうございますm(__)m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP と同じように HTML 埋め込みを行いたいのであれば `eRuby` があります。1.8 系から標準ライブラリとして同梱されています。

HTML には以下のように埋め込むことができます。

```
<html>
<head><title>サンプル</title></head>
<body>
<p><% puts "Hello!" %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: もう一つ、もし簡単な web アプリケーションを実装したい場合はフレームワークになってしまいますが、http://www.sinatrarb.com/ Sinatra という小さなフレームワークがあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、試してみます！

Answer (score 0):

この解答は一種のジョークのようなものなのですが、「Ruby コードを HTML に埋め込み、ブラウザで閲覧時に実行させたい」に対する実現案として、RubyコードをJavaScriptの様にブラウザ側で実行させる手段があります（というかありました）。

MicrosoftのSilverlight関連のIronRubyという技術に関するものです。

[サンプル](http://www.visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/samples/getting.started/01_ruby.html)

といってもこのサンプルは現在は動作しないようなのですが、何らかの条件を整えると、このようにブラウザでRubyが実行できたようです。HTMLソースコードの「`<script type="text/ruby">`」という部分にRubyコードがあります。

ただしこれは古い技術で今どうなっているのかよくわかりません。現在でも環境を整えると実行できるようになるのかも定かではありません。

ただ、万が一このような実行方法を求めているのなら、IronRuby関連を調べることをお勧めします。ただし、Ruby以外の種々の知識も必要になるはずですので、他のやり方が出来るならまずはそちらをお勧めします。

Comment: IronRuby はこちらで動作確認ができます。

http://ironruby.net/try/

あまりにも不正確な情報は混乱を生じるだけだと思います。

Comment: IronRubyでRubyのHTML埋め込みが可能だと紹介し、もし必要ならここらへんを調べるといいという情報を示しただけのつもりです。紹介いただいたようなブラウザ上で実行するものとは実行形態が異なりますので、参考にはなりませんでした。

Comment: 上記コメントを補足します。私の解答が包括的な情報を提供していないのは認めますが、不正確ではありませんのご指摘には当たらないはずです。また「参考にはなりませんでした」とは、紹介していただいたリンクは実行形態が異なりますので、私の解答で不足していた情報の参考にはなりませんでした、という意味です。

Comment: 私も言葉が足りず少々尖った物言いになってしまい申し訳ありませんでした。私が不正確であると指摘したかったのは、具体的には次の一文です。`ただしこれは古い技術で今どうなっているのかよくわかりません。現在でも環境を整えると実行できるようになるのかも定かではありません。` 定かではないようなものをジョークにしても初学者に勧めるべきではないと思いますし、"IronRuby はちゃんと動くモノなんですよ" という意味を込めて補足(コメント)しました。またリンク先が /try だったことも混乱の原因だったと思います、申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: なるほどその点でしたか。そこもこちらの言葉足らずだったようです。それについても「IronRubyでRubyのHTML埋め込みが可能」という点についてです。

用意されているサンプル（上に張ったリンク）を幾つかのブラウザで実行してみたのですが動作しなかったので、この形態での実行を最終的に動作させることができるのかどうか確信が持てませんでした。

（なお自分が過去に動作させれた時は、このような誰にでも実行できる形ではなく、クライアント側に環境を作る必要がありました）